# HTC One SMS Backup File with no Extension Restore issue

Tags: sms, restore, htc

I backed up my SMS an year ago via HTC One phone's messaging application. The backup file that was created on SD card had no extension and its name is "SMS_nai_SD_20160625_701301_0".

I was never able to restore that backup but I now need one of the messages in backup and have already lost the phone. If I open the file in notepad, it starts with "HTCMSGBACKUP_V1" and rest of that are special characters. There is [another thread related to same issue](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36425/how-to-extract-sms-from-an-htc-one-ics-sms-backup-file) that suggests either restore the messages or use emulator. I was wondering is there any other way to handle that if we know the starting characters of the file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the file extension will not help. As far as I know it's just some kind of encrypted text file. It's either a htc or an android specific file. In order to restore a message from that file you need an android device. It might work with the stock android sms app in an emulator but probably not. I suspect that it's only going to work with htc sms app.

**[edit]:**
The backup file is an encrypted sqlite database file not just some text file.

Comment: I think you are right, it must be an encrypted file. I do have Huawei 5X which is also an android phone. But this file is not recognizable on that even. I have also tried "SMS Backup & Reset", "All SmS Secure", "Super Backup" and Huawei built in SMS app for the purpose. None of them is working. Can you please suggest how would I do this via emulator?

Comment: Based on your test it's not going to work with a stock android emulator. You can try to install the htc sms app (htc messages) on your huawei. http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/htc-corporation/htc-messages/messages-8-00-756259-release/messages-8-00-756259-android-apk-download/

Comment: 2 out of 4 available versions could be installed. App kept restoring for some time, when restoring finished, it shown me blank messages from correct contacts. Message body was missing. It was a close miss! Thank you for the help. Any other tip?

Comment: I believe the only remaining thing you could do is to get a hold on an htc phone and to restore the backup with that phone.  If you are into "cracking/hacking" you could also try to crack the file. The backup file is an encrypted sqlite database file so you would need to crack the encryption. I cannot help you with that.